# Implementing a Game GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

The goal in mind is to take the text-based game and wrap it in a GUI (not really anything advanced, just a window). I know how JFrames works, so would this be as simple as creating the JFrame GUI and writing out the game using:

```
g.drawString(str, x, y);
```

The problems I'd see myself running into would be any user input. Receiving yes/no answers, setting/getting variables, or putting code -into- the JFrame.

Actually, can methods be called into "g.drawString();", or is there some sort of function to call a method into a JFrame? If so, this would answer my question.

Comment: Why don't you use `JTextArea` and work with plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call function inside `drawString()`

The first parameter of `drawString()` is a `String` object, so a function returning `String` can be called inside `drawString()`.

Example

```
public String foo(){
  String str ="";


  //modify string

  return str;
}
```

calling `foo()` inside `drawString()`

```
g.drawString(foo(),x,y);
```

Comment: Is setting the x and y values required if calling a method, or not? I figure a method doesn't need parameters for where it's going to appear at. And, my methods return String outputs (there's a method for getting/setting user input, and calling the date based on the system time). This still works, right?

Comment: @Jarvis x and  y are parameters of `drawString` and they are compulsory.

Comment: This is actually proving to be a bit more difficult than I originally expected. The methods must be of type String and return a result of type String, and none of my methods do such. Most, for instance, are methods such as: `static public void create() {}` which runs the character-creation function, asking for the user's name, age, gender and race and setting these results into variables in another class. I don't think I can implement this function into the JFrame, at least, not using `g.drawString();`.